# Proper way to detect on button click on a Dynamic Listview Appearance

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

My listview is set to dynamic appearance. It has 2 TListItemTextButtons on it. I want to assign a sort of "OnClick" event to each of those buttons on each items.

The thing is Almost every listview items needs a different proc to run on it and I know exactly how to do it. When I normally create a dynamic TButton I can assign a custom proc to it using `AnonProc2NotifyEvent` from [TProc<TObject> to TNotifyEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491593/tproctobject-to-tnotifyevent).

I'm aware of the `OnItemClickEx` a normal listview has but it seems a little buggy. Example: lets say Listviewitem has a itemindex of 3 and you as a user click on the button in listviewitem 1 then the button from listviewitem 3 will activate.

How can I go about assigning a `OnClick` for a TListItemTextButton?

Example of what I want to do:

```
LItem.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('Username').Text := 'Some username';
LItem.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('Info').Text := 'Some extra info';

LItem.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemTextButton>('Kick').OnClick := AnonProc2NotifyEvent(lvPlayers,
procedure(Sender: TObject)
begin
SendRconCommand('removeconnection ' + jplayers['userid'].AsString);
end);
```

However this provides a Undeclared Identifier for OnClick.

Comment: Please provide a [reprex]. The simplest form and components structure that demonstrate what you have so far, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to assign a OnClick event for a TListItemTextButton. Emba docs says it has such an event but I cannot seem to access it and only get undeclared Identifier. I editted the question providing the doc link.

Comment: Emba docs also say that the `OnClick` event does not exist anymore (or it is not documented) after Seattle. Which version do you have (is it really AppMethod)?

Comment: I have Rio 10.3.2 Is there anyway around this then?

Comment: I don't know, and I don't want to spend time on trying to create a representative test case. Oh, and the newest version I have installed is Berlin (10.1)

Comment: My bad. I looked at the wrong docs. There is no OnClick for Rio like you mentioned http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.ListView.Types.TListItemTextButton_Events

Comment: So you know the right event is `OnSelect`, and you don't need a separate one for each ListItemTextButton. The `Sender` parameter tells you which one fired the event.

Comment: On Select fires even if the list item is selected. No matter what you click on it fires.